# Android service doesn't restart when I close app

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm doing some tests with services. My code in local service is just:

```
function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
  my_log('Service started');
end;
```

But service doesn't restart when I close the app. I know that a local service runs in the same process as the app so it is normal the service finish, but START_STICKY should start the service automatically but this is not happening. The service only starts automatically when I open the application again.
Is this a Delphi issue? In applications made in Java the service starts correctly.

I'm running on Android 10.

Comment: If you run the same code on an earlier (< Android 10) device, do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check battery settings for your app (just to be sure that you have not restricted run of background service)